# How to configure Farsun FG9800 USB barcode scanner to not auto-enter after each scan

Tags: barcode-scanner

Does anyone know how to program it so it does not place a carriage return/enter after every scan? That function is messing up my program that I scan inventory into since it executes the enter command when I have more fields to scan in.

Comment: Most barcode scanner's i've come across have the 'enter after every line/scan' as an option in the driver or firmware of the device. Have you checked the documentation/contacted support for the device?

Comment: I have and there are many configurations in the manual but none that I have tried to remove the enter carriage after each scan.

Comment: Check for other firmware, or by contacting the vendor as this is probably by design.

Answer (score 0):

In the programming manual I have it doesn't have the exact option you want for a predefined bar code that you can scan, but you can however make one.

If you have the manual under the page "termination string setup bar codes" there is "String #2 - Code 128 termination char - CR (FNC3)0202021080$0D" which if you scan it will make it press enter after a scan. If you change the last two characters to "(FNC3)0202021080$09" it will tab for you.

NOTE: FNC3 is the "code 128 program character"

I used P-Touch to make this bar code label, it is a label making program by Brother for its label printers.

[image]

After you scan the label it should beep indicating that it has set the new value.

You should also be able to program it to do whatever you need it to, I have made several programming bar codes from the manual to change the option(s) for what program that I happen to be using.